# after switching to art phone stuck in bootloop

Tags: settings

i have a supersonic android tablet i switched to art when it restarted it stuck on the android lolgo but the silver light is still flashing on it NB. i left it there for about 2 half hours

Comment: Are you rooted or do you have a custom recovery?

Comment: Probably not all your system files are compatible with the new runtime. Can you get to recovery or bootloader?